# What is the problem with using an instance of the following class to share between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, distributed-computing

I'm being asked what is the problem of using an instance of the following class to share between threads.
What are the risks? And what are possible solutions?

```
public class States {

    private String[] states = new String[] {
        "UNK", "NEW", "RUNNING", "DONE"
    };

    public String[] getStates() {
        return states;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem with this code is that although arrays are immutable in java but because you expose a reference to the array, nothing prevents anyone to reassign the whole array with a new one. It is better to use enum classes for this use case.

Comment: As long as nobody is modifying the array, it looks thread safe.

Comment: No one outside the class can create a new array and assign its reference to this. They can only mutate the array

Comment: So the issue would be someone could use the method getStates() and then do something like states[0] = 'fakeState', right?

Comment: @Someone That is right. But it is not related to multiple threads (or multithreading). It is true for single threaded apps too